# How can I retrieve a value from string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"text1 <text2> text3"
```

I want to grab only the text in `<>`. So I need to get `text2`. How can I do it?

Comment: Mandatory link: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String value = "text1 <text2> text3 <text4>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
text2
text4
```

**Response Update:**

Assuming that you know that you have only one value to extract, [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) proposes a simpler approach, he proposes to proceed as next:

```
String value = "text1 <text2> text3";
String target = value.replaceAll(".*<(.*)>.*", "$1");
System.out.println(target);
```

**Output:**

```
text2
```

Comment: you can do it with way less code than that...

Comment: It's not even a line, it needs just a method call: `String target = value.replaceAll(".*<(.*)>.*", "$1");`. Less code == less bugs, easier to read and maintain.

Comment: the question clearly asks about getting only one value from the input. The simplest solution is always the best.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to split this string using " " as a separator - you will get 3 -elements array and the second one is what you are looking for